# Problem with Julia function - output not displaying double difference

Tags: function, for-loop, julia

I am new to julia and am trying to create a function in which calculates a double difference between events for a set of receivers and puts all these double differences into a vector, however my function output is this

```
(::var"#d#8 {Array{Float64,2},Array{Float64,2},Int64,Int64}) (generic function with 1 method)
```

Here is the code:

```
function doubledifference(obsEvents, calcEvents)
    I = size(obsEvents, 2) #event 1
    J = size(obsEvents, 2) #event 2
    K = size(obsEvents, 1) #receiver
    M = ((K*I)*(K - 1))/2
    M = Int(M)
    d = zeros(M, 1)
    n = 1 #d position counter
    for i = 1:I #i.e. no. columns in matrix
        for j = 1:J
            for k = 1:K
                if j <= i
                    j = j + 1
                else d(n) = (obsEvents(k, i) - obsEvents(k, j)) - (calcEvents(k, i) - calcEvents(k, j))
                    n = n + 1
                end
            end
        end
    end
    
    return d
end
```

Comment: `M = ((K*I)*(K - 1))/2` is floating point division, which is why you have to convert to `Int` afterwards. It's better to use integer division directly, with the `div` function. Also, a vector is not the same as an nx1 matrix, so I recommend `d = zeros(M)` instead of `zeros(M, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty alright, because it *is* the printed output of the function.

```
d(n) = (obsEvents(k, i) - obsEvents(k, j)) - (calcEvents(k, i) - calcEvents(k, j))
```

declares a local function, aka closure, with an anonymous type `var"#d#8`, and parameter `n`, which internally calls other functions (!) `obsEvents` and `calcEvents`.  The function name `d` shadows the array `d`.  That function is returned.

[**Julia is not Matlab**](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/).  Array indexing uses square brackets:

```
d[n] = (obsEvents[k, i] - obsEvents[k, j]) - (calcEvents[k, i] - calcEvents[k, j])
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was going to be a stupid mistake in there

Comment: No worries. If the answer suits you, you can click the checkmark next to the upvote buttons to accept it.